# Does history diverge in git if I use cherry picks or manually edit files?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, cherry-pick

I have a development branch called `main`, a staging branch called `staging` and production branch called `production`. I want to push a hotfix to production branch.

First I created a new branch off `main`:

```
git checkout main
git checkout -b hotfix
```

Then I merged the branch to `main`:

```
git checkout main
git merge hotfix
```

then merged the branch to `staging` in order to deploy first to staging environment and check that the branch works:

```
git checkout staging
git merge hotfix
```

Now I want to merge the hotfix branch to `production` however merging brings a lot of other changes not-related to the hotfix. These other changes were not checked in `staging` environment yet so I don't want to have them in `production`. Therefore I decided to just `cherry-pick` the commits related to the hotfix from the `hotfix` branch into `production`. I also had some conflicts when cherry-picking.

I'm wondering though if in the future there will be changes to the regions of code which I cherry-picked in `main` and `staging`, will they be reflected in `production`? I'm afraid that git will not reflect them because of the cherry-pick and conflicts.

Is there a better way to handle hotfixes in git so that the above issues don't occur?

Comment: Show a diagram for your graph.

Comment: Cherry-pick makes a new commit based on some existing commit. That's pretty much it. Is a new commit *divergent* history? That depends on how you define "divergent". History is commits; commits are history; but "divergent" is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but about this part:

> I'm wondering though if in the future there will be changes to the regions of code which I cherry-picked in main and staging, will they be reflected in production? I'm afraid that git will not reflect them because of the cherry-pick and conflicts.

When you cherry-pick, git "replays" the changes that commit introduced, and apply those changed on the target branch, making a new (and different) commit. This commit has no links to the one you cherry-picked, so Git will never be aware of anything that happens on the "other side", conflicts resolution or not.